# Creating a 2D grid for a board game in python

Tags: python, grid

I'm taking an introductory course to computer science using Python and we were given an exercise to make a board game(dogems). I'm having troubles constructing the board. The program is suppose to take a given argument and, using a function make_board(size), constructs a board of equal rows and columns with numbers along the bottom and letters along the side. A function show_board(board) then displays it.
e.g. Board size:4 would give:

```
a . . .
b . . .
c . . .
. 1 2 3
```

whereas, a board size:5 would give:

```
a . . . .
b . . . .
c . . . .
d . . . .
. 1 2 3 4
```

My question is basically, how would I go about writing these functions to construct a board of this nature?

Comment: In general, when it comes to homework, it's nice to see a bit of code up front, just as a show of good faith.

Answer (score 8):

Try starting with something really simple, like printing out just the bottom row:

```
. 1 2 3 4 5
```

That's pretty easy

```
print '.', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
```

Now what if I want to have a variable sized board?

Let's try a loop

```
for i in range(length+1):
    if i == 0:
        print '.'
    else:
        print i
```

Note that you need a variable length.

Ok what about the columns? These are letters, how can we print a variable length list of letters?

As you tackle these little problems one by one, you will start to realize what variables become apparent. Maybe you decide that storing a list of lists is the best way to do it, so `make_board(size)` returns something like a list of of lists of characters, and `show_board(board)` uses a for loop within a for loop to print it all out.

Don't expect the finished solution from StackOverflow, try doing some of this stuff and ask a question when you really get stuck!

Comment: +1 for "try doing some of this stuff and ask a question when you really get stuck"

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice but, i'm having troubles in using the given value for my variable length and wherever else i need to use it.

One part of my code is:</br>
PROMPT_SIZE = "Board size: "</br>

def getGameSize():</br>
 result = input(PROMPT_SIZE)</br>
 return int(result)</br>

Then I try to use the "int(result)" value later in an if statement but, the program tells me it isn't defined. How do I assign this value to something that I can use in the rest of my code?

Comment: You need to open a new question with your code properly formatted. Good for you for getting started though! `size = getGameSize()` might be what you need, but really it's impossible to say from your comment, go open a new question and post all the relevant code.